# How to get the unique from UNION according to some condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable, informix

if i make a union between multiple queries (4 for example) and i get the following

result :

```
id  name    num
13  task1   0
13  task1   7102
```

---

How to get only the **unique** where num is greater than 0 if there are more than one record with the same id in the union statement .

---

```
foreach 
SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code,
                a.task_name ,
                0 AS cand_num INTO ll_task_code ,
                                   ls_task_name,
                                   ll_cand_num
FROM rmtask a,
     rmtaskstate b,
     rmstateuser c
WHERE (a.task_code = b.task_code)
  AND (b.state_code = c.state_code)
  AND (c.emp_num = al_emp_num)
  AND (al_new_flag = 0
       OR (al_new_flag = 1
           AND b.new_flag = 1))
UNION --candidate

SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code,
                a.task_name ,
                cand.emp_num
FROM rmtask a,
     rmtaskstate b,
     rmstateuser c ,
     rmcandidate cand
WHERE (a.task_code = b.task_code)
  AND (b.state_code = c.state_code)
  AND (c.emp_num = cand.emp_num)
  AND (al_new_flag = 0
       OR (al_new_flag = 1
           AND b.new_flag = 1))
  AND (cand.task_code = b.task_code)
  AND (cand.emp_num_candidate = al_emp_num)
  AND (cand.from_date <= DATE(CURRENT))
  AND (cand.to_date >= DATE(CURRENT)
       OR cand.to_date IS NULL)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code,
                a.task_name ,
                0 AS cand_num
FROM rmtask a,
     rmtaskstate b,
     rmstategroup c
WHERE (a.task_code = b.task_code) )
UNION --candidate

SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code,
                a.task_name ,
                cand.emp_num
FROM rmtask a,
     rmtaskstate b,
     rmstategroup c ,
     rmcandidate cand
WHERE (a.task_code = b.task_code)
  AND (b.state_code= c.state_code)
  AND (al_new_flag = 0
       OR (al_new_flag = 1
           AND b.new_flag = 1))
  AND (((c.group_type = 0))
       OR ((c.group_type = 1)
           AND (c.group_code =
                  (SELECT x.degree_code
                   FROM hr_l x
                   WHERE x.emp_num = cand.emp_num
                     AND x.degree_date =
                       (SELECT max(xx.degree_date)
                        FROM hm xx
                        WHERE xx.emp_num = x.emp_num))))
       OR ((c.group_type = 2)
           AND (c.group_code =
                  (SELECT y.title_code
                   FROM ht y
                   WHERE y.emp_num = cand.emp_num
                     AND y.title_date =
                       (SELECT max(yy.title_date)
                        FROM ht yy
                        WHERE yy.emp_num = y.emp_num))))
       OR ((c.group_type = 3)
           AND (1 = r_boss(cand.emp_num)))
       OR ((c.group_type = 4)
           AND (0 <
                  (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM ht x
                   WHERE x.emp_num = cand.emp_num
                     AND x.perm_flag = 1)))
       OR ((c.group_type = 5)
           AND (0 <
                  (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM hm x
                   WHERE x.emp_num = cand.emp_num
                     AND x.vac_flag = 1)))
       OR ((c.group_type = 6)
           AND (0 <
                  (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM hm x
                   WHERE x.emp_num = cand.emp_num
                     AND x.mission_flag = 1))))
  AND (cand.task_code = b.task_code)
  AND (cand.emp_num_candidate = al_emp_num)
  AND (cand.from_date <= DATE(CURRENT))
  AND (cand.to_date >= DATE(CURRENT)
       OR cand.to_date IS NULL) RETURN ll_task_code ,
                                       ls_task_name,
                                       ll_cand_num WITH resume ;
end foreach;
```

Comment: `num` i want the `num` column unique and if there are many columns with the same id get only the one with `num` greater than 0

Comment: Unless informix implements `UNION` in a non-standard manner, there should be no need to apply `distinct` to each of those queries.

Comment: It [doesn't appear to](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqlt108.htm): "The UNION keyword selects all rows from the two queries, removes duplicates, and returns what is left"

Comment: Might there be multiple non-zero `num`s? If so, what should be returned? One row (if so, what's the rule?), or all non-zero rows?

Comment: if there are more than one record with the same `id` .get the record with `num != 0`

Comment: I was asking if there might be *more* than one row with `num != 0`. Do we have to cope with that?

Comment: no .with the same id never .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: What do you think UNION is supposed to do differently?  Are you confusing UNION ALL with plain UNION?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I was trying to point out that `UNION` (by itself) already removes duplicates. As such, putting `DISTINCT` in to each `SELECT` of a `UNION` is at best redundant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Oh, I see what you were saying now...OK; perhaps not as clearly written as it could be, but it does make sense when you know what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use JOIN notation instead of comma lists in the FROM clause.
2. We rally don't need to see all your query to give an answer; two parts to the union would be sufficient.
3. You've not mentioned the version of Informix you're using, which can make a difference.
4. It would be easier if your example output tied in with the SQL you write.  Your sample output uses `id`, `name`, `num`, but the SQL seems to use `task_code`, `task_name`, and `cand_num`.
5. It would appear that you want the maximum candidate number for a given task code and task name.

So, write the query like that:

```
SELECT u.task_code, u.task_name, MAX(u.cand_num)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code, a.task_name, 0 AS cand_num
          FROM rmtask a
          JOIN rmtaskstate b ON a.task_code = b.task_code
          JOIN rmstateuser c ON b.state_code = c.state_code
         WHERE (c.emp_num = al_emp_num)
           AND (al_new_flag = 0 OR (al_new_flag = 1 AND b.new_flag = 1))
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT a.task_code, a.task_name, cand.emp_num
          FROM rmtask a
          JOIN rmtaskstate b ON a.task_code = b.task_code
          JOIN rmstateuser c ON b.state_code = c.state_code
          JOIN rmcandidate cand ON c.emp_num = cand.emp_num
         WHERE (al_new_flag = 0 OR (al_new_flag = 1 AND b.new_flag = 1))
           AND (cand.task_code = b.task_code)
           AND (cand.emp_num_candidate = al_emp_num)
           AND (cand.from_date <= DATE(CURRENT))
           AND (cand.to_date >= DATE(CURRENT) OR cand.to_date IS NULL)
       ) AS u
 GROUP BY u.task_code, u.task_name;
```

Clearly, you can add the other alternative UNION branches inside the sub-query.

Comment: thanks a lot .I have a question: Why (`Join`) notation instead of (,) although when using `JOIN` notation ,i should take care of the order of my tables in the query which make me a little confused !

Comment: The comma list in the FROM clause was the old, pre-SQL92 way of doing business before the JOIN notation was supported.  The primary problem is that you can't see what join conditions are nearly as easily when they're buried in the WHERE clause.  There are questions on SO about why to use JOIN instead of comma; you can get other people's view on the issue from those.

Answer (score 1):

If there's just one row with `num != 0`, or you only need one result, then putting the existing query in a subquery and using `GROUP BY` and an aggregate would be indicated:

```
select id,name,MAX(num) as num
from
   (
       select id,name,num from abc
       union
       select id,name,num from def
       union
       select id,name,num from ghi
   ) as t
group by id,name
```

Comment: Could u clarify what do u mean by Existing query .I update my question with my query

Comment: the 'num` field isn't exist in the table abc i have to use `0 as cand_num`